# Permission denied on cifs mount of Win2008R2 folder in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, cifs

Hi there Ubuntu experts!
I have troubles mounting a Windows 2008R2 Enterprise shared location in a Ubuntu VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"

Here is my error:

```
root@myserver:~# mount -t cifs -v -o user=sambauser,password=mypass,vers=2.1 //MYDWBLD/linux32_release /mnt/mnt.ntfs

mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=16.59.65.71,unc=\\MYDWBLD\linux32_release,vers=2.1,user=sambauser,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I tried all sorts of option, such as *sec=ntlm*,*domain=MYDWBLD* but none of them helped, I get same error. I even created a local Administrator account to use ( different from the LDAP user ), still same result.
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible problem - you are missing `sec` section. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124342/mount-error-13-permission-denied

Comment: I've tried all the available options from sec parameter as well, without success.

Comment: What are the permissions of your mountpoint (`ls -ld /mnt/mnt.ntfs`)?

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan 22 16:38 /mnt/mnt.ntfs/

Comment: Try to put your credentials into a file.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue! The command is correct, problem was special character `$` in my password. The password was something like `abcde$fge1` and I had to escape it like `abcde\$fge1` then it worked just fine! Thanks to everyone for suggestions!

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the solution. You get points and we don't see it as an unanswered question anymore.